# Change the styling of default alert box

Tags: html, css

Could someone please tell me how can I change the default css of a alert/prompt box ?

Comment: No, you can't. It's handled by the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. They are native to the browser and are not styl-able.

You should turn to javascript alert-like systems. Using jQuery, here are some:

- [jAlert](http://www.smooka.com/blog/2009/02/22/jalert-jquery-alert-box-plugin/)
- [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (with some tweaking)
- This [page](http://cool-javascripts.com/modal-windows/three-jquery-modal-plugins-to-repace-alert-and-confirm.html) proposes three alternatives to native alert/confirm/prompt

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914126/123127) shows a way to have a confirm-like blocking dialog using jquery ui dialog

Answer (score 2):

As noted above you may always use the jQuery Alert box...

But you may also fire a JavaScript/jQuery Function in which displays a DIV (HTML Element), in which you may style completely.

Answer (score 2):

The alert box that is used by javaScript is part of the browser. (other poeple have pointed this out but if you would like to have a good starting point try this.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#default 
jQuery Ui has some great tools for creating your own alert box and will also having other helpful options.
Just wanted to give some more information.

Answer (score 1):

The `alert` box is built into the Browser.  You will need to popup your own dialog.  The jQueryUI is very good for this.

For an example on this, look on the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) site.