# change font of alert in behind code

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I used below code for showing message in my page

```
if (Session["Message"] != null)
    {

        //Write message code here
        this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('insert succesfullyا')</script>");

        Session["Message"] = null;
    }
```

I want this message show with (`font=Tahoma  font-size=12px and  font-weight:bold` )

How I can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the style of alert box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853130/how-to-change-the-style-of-alert-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, its not possible.

You have to use custom alert box.Using jQuery, here are some:

- [jAlert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198023/change-the-styling-of-default-alert-box)
- [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (with some tweaking)
- This [page](http://cool-javascripts.com/modal-windows/three-jquery-modal-plugins-to-repace-alert-and-confirm.html) proposes three alternatives to native alert/confirm/prompt

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914126/123127) shows a way to have a confirm-like blocking dialog using jquery ui dialog

**Check this already answered SO Question:** [Change the styling of default alert box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198023/change-the-styling-of-default-alert-box)